# Verifying that the system clocks are set correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, time, clock

I'm working on an application which uses WordPress and LAMP stack. Now, I'm encountering some issues in my application while working with Twitter OAuth, and someone suggested that I verify that my system settings are correct.

I'm working on the localhost currently, so I'm assuming that what I have to do is verify whether my local system clock is in sync with my local server's clock settings. I do know that to check the current clock settings of my local system, I can simply type `date` in the terminal.

How do I find out the current clock settings of my development environment? Or maybe do I have to check the clock settings of my MySQL database? Do I need to access phpMyAdmin? If yes, where could I find the development environment's clock settings? And how do I ensure that my system's clock settings are correct?

Sorry if I'm asking way too many questions, but I'm not really sure I know how to verify whether my clock settings are in sync.

Comment: There's no "development's environment's clock". There's a service for Linux systems that keeps your system clock in sync all the time. It's called `ntpdate`.